# Why is b=`git branch` different from just git branch

Tags: bash, git

I don't understand the behavior of Bash in this case:

If I type `git branch`, I get a list of branches.

BUT if I try to put it into a variable, say, `` b=`git branch`; echo $b ``, I get an output as if I made `ls; git branch`. The content of a directory is listed together with the branches.

Could someone please explain this behavior?

Answer (score 7):

`git branch` indicates the current branch using `*`. When you run

```
b=`git branch`; echo $b
```

since `$b` is used unquoted with `echo`, this `*` is expanded by the shell, showing the files in the current directory. Quoting will avoid that:

```
b=`git branch`; echo "$b"
```